# Difference between two foreach (adding new elements to the array)

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Why does **[this](http://ideone.com/CCOIX)** foreach:

```
$abc = array('a','b');
foreach ($abc as $k => &$a) {
    echo $a;    
        $abc[] = 'c';
        if ($k > 5) die;
}
```

Outputs this:

```
abccccc
```

And **[this](http://ideone.com/31oxj)** one:

```
$abc = array('a');
foreach ($abc as $k => &$a) {
    echo $a;    
    $abc[] = 'c';
    if ($k > 5) die;
}
```

Outputs this:

```
a
```

I expected both foreaches behaving the same way (iterating until key = 6).

Comment: Modifying the object you're looping over in a foreach loop is a bad idea. It is not recommended. Edit contents as they come or not at all and you'll steer clear of a ton of headache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the second foreach doesn't event foreaches a second time, i.e. does only one iteration, therefore even if an element is added, the addition happens when the foreach is already over (it starts with the idea that it has only one element, and it hasn't to go on looping)

Comment: Optimizations... oh well. Thanks! :)